# Search a pattern and print preceding lines starting with another pattern

Tags: text-processing, grep

I need to grep for a pattern and once I find it, I need to look for another pattern preceding that and print all those lines in between those.

Better example:

```
1 a
2 a
3 a
4 a
5 a
6 b
7 c
8 d
9 xyz
10 xyz
11 a
12 a
```

Grep for `xyz` and then grep for first `a` preceding `xyz` line and print all the lines.

Output (first preceding occurrence of `a`, I don;t care about other `a`'s in the file):

```
5 a 
6 b
7 c
8 d
9  xyz
10 xyz
```

Comment: What OS and what version of `grep`?

Comment: Is what you want is to eliminate duplicates @user1413813

Comment: No i dont want to remove duplicates. i want to get the first occurrence of "8000-1 blah test1" preceding "xyz" and then print the lines between those (including those lines)

Comment: You show two “xyz” lines in the input, and you show both of them in the output. Please describe the behavior you want. Do you want the output to continue to the last “xyz” in the file? E.g., if lines 9-12 were “xyz”, “foo”, “xyz”, “bar”, would you want the output to be lines 5-11? I ask because you say, “I need to grep for a pattern *(“xyz”)* and once I find *(it)*, I need to look for another pattern *(“a”)* preceding that …”, which sounds like you want find the *first* “xyz”. Also, what if lines 9-14 were “xyz”, “b”, “a”, “r”, “xyz”, “foo”? Would you want lines 5-13 or just 11-13?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in Perl:

```
perl -nlE '
    if    (/a/)   { @buffer = ($_) }
    elsif (/xyz/) { push @buffer,$_; say for @buffer }
    else          { push @buffer,$_}
' your_file
```

**How this works**

It reads through the file line-by-line and does one of three things:

1. If the current line matches the pattern `a`, it assigns the current line to the `@buffer` array.
2. If the current line matches the pattern `xyz`, it pushes the current line onto the buffer and prints the contents of the buffer
3. If none of the two cases above is true, it simply appends the current line to the `@buffer` array.

Thus, whenever a new line matches the pattern `a`, the contents of the `@buffer` are erased and replaced by the current line only. This guarantees you will find the closest `a` preceding `xyz`.

You should of course replace the regexes I used with the actual regexes relevant to your case.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you could do something like

```
grep -zPo '.*a(?s)(?(?!a).)*?xyz' file
```

(with GNU grep, if your version is recent enough to support the PCRE extension) or

```
pcregrep -Mo '.*a(?s)(?(?!a).)*?xyz' file
```

If you want to match to the second instance of `xyz` in your output, make the match greedy by removing the final `?` e.g. `grep -zPo '.*a(?s)(?(?!a).)*xyz' file`.

---

Perhaps a better test is this, with multi-character patterns for both the start and stop condition; given

```
$ cat file
1 abc    
2 abc
3 abc
4 abc
5 abc
6 bbc
7 cbc
8 dbc
9 xyz
10 xyz
11 abc
12 abc
```

then

```
$ grep -zPo '.*abc(?s)(?(?!abc).)*?xyz' file
5 abc
6 bbc
7 cbc
8 dbc
9 xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tac file | sed '/xyz/,/a/!d' | tac
```

(if you don't have `tac`, your `tail` command may have a `-r` command to do the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care blank lines in output, try:

```
$ awk '
    !NF { next }
    /a/ { flag = 1; last = $0; next }
    last && flag { print last; print; last = 0; next}
    /xyz/ { print; flag = 0; next}
    flag
' file
5 a
6 b
7 c
8 d
9 xyz
10 xyz
```