# How parse a log file for a string, and when found search backwards for another string

Tags: shell-script, command-line

I use the following command to parse a log file for a particular string. Then I search backwards in the log to find the data I really want.  The problem as in the example below, I am only going back 50 lines.  It is unknown if the text I am looking for will be 5 lines back, 200 lines back or more.  Is there a way to search through a log file for a particular string, and when that string is found, to then search backwards through the log to find a 2nd string despite not knowing how far back the 2nd string is located.  Also there could be multiple occurrence of the 1st string.  So for for every instance of the 1st string, I want to be able to search backwards to collect the data from the second string.

```
grep -B50 "Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:" LCSoap_8.log | \
tac | grep -P -o '(?<=qualified-src-dn=).*(?=src-dn)'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search a pattern and print preceding lines starting with another pattern](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146641/search-a-pattern-and-print-preceding-lines-starting-with-another-pattern)

Comment: @steeldriver, no, they are different questions, though similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tac LCSoap_8.log | sed -n '
  /Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:/,/qualified-src-dn=.*src-dn/!d
  s/.*qualified-src-dn=\(.*\)src-dn.*/\1/p'
```

or to reuse your `grep`:

```
tac LCSoap_8.log | sed '
  /Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:/,/qualified-src-dn=.*src-dn/!d' |
  grep -Po '(?<=qualified-src-dn=).*(?=src-dn)'
```

`sed '/A/,B/!d'` d̲eletes every line except (!̲) those from `A̲` to the next `B̲` after that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible PCRE-based solution based on a similar question [Search a pattern and print preceding lines starting with another pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146641/search-a-pattern-and-print-preceding-lines-starting-with-another-pattern)

```
grep -zPo '.*abc.*(?=(?s)(?(?!abc).)*?xyz)' file
```

will output the last line containing `abc` that occurs before each instance of `xyz`

e.g. given a file

```
1 abc
2 abc
3 abc
4 abc
5 abc
6 bcd
7 cde
8 def
9 xyz
10 xyz
```

then

```
$ grep -zPo '.*abc.*(?=(?s)(?(?!abc).)*?xyz)' file
5 abc
```